# Enabling security on worklight server 6.1 console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Trying to setup security on a 6.1 worklight server (Full WAS 8.5.5)

Getting error:

```
SRVE0232E: Internal Server Error. 
Exception Message: [com.ibm.websphere.servlet.session.UnauthorizedSessionRequestException: SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/uid=wasadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm.]


com.ibm.websphere.servlet.session.UnauthorizedSessionRequestException: SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/uid=wasadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm.


IBM WebSphere Application Server
```

I have edited the following files before deploying the new WAR file...

worklight.properties:

```
#######################################################################################################################
#   Protecting the Worklight Console
#######################################################################################################################
# You can protect the Worklight Console by defining user credentials required to access it.
# In addition to defining these two properties, you should also configure the authenticationConfig.xml file,
# located under <Worklight Root Directory>\server\conf.
console.username=consoleadmin
console.password=consolepassword
```

Authenticationconfig.xml:

```
    <!-- Uncomment the next element to protect the worklight console and the first section in securityTests below. -->
     <staticResources>
        <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="WorklightConsole">
            <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
         </resource> 

        <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>
    </staticResources> 

   <!--  Sample security tests  
         Even if not used there will be some default webSecurityTest and mobileSecurityTest 
         Attention: if using <testAppAuthenticity/> test below ,<publicSigningKey> element must be added to application-descriptor.xml as well. -->   

     <securityTests>

        <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
            <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        <!--
        <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
            <testAppAuthenticity/> 
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
        </mobileSecurityTest>

        <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
            <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/>
        </webSecurityTest>

        <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        -->
        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>       

    </securityTests>
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access session from unprotected page. Check in the admin console in `Security > Global security > Web and SIP security > General settings` if you have `Use available authentication data when an unprotected URI is accessed` checkbox checked.

Comment: Should be noted this is not the way to protect Worklight Console in production environments (that is, outside of the development server): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html ---- Use LDAP.

Comment: @gas - That check box is already ticked

Comment: @IdanAdar - Can you point me to the help page detailing securing the worklight console for Prod without LDAP please?

Comment: The same link I posted above...

Comment: @IdanAdar - all that link says is "Note: Setting user credentials in this way is not a suitable method for protecting Worklight Console access in a production environment. Use an alternative method such as LDAP instead." - what are the alternatives to LDAP and where can information be found to configure this for a PROD environment?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be related to the following questions:

- [SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868734/sesn0008e-a-user-authenticated-as-anonymous-has-attempted-to-access-a-session-o)
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3ea7b2ae-b9f2-422d-8739-433fa01a190d